# Xcode error: Class <name> is implemented in both <path> and <path>. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined?

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

I made a `Unity` project with `Firebase SDK's (v 8.7.0)` and I'm trying to build it for iOS with `Xcode`. I'm using `Cocoapods (v 1.11.2)` for the `Firebase SDK`'s to work in `Xcode`.

I build my `Unity` project and installed `Cocoapods` which generated the xcworkspace file to open in `Xcode`. When I try to run the app on a connected `iPhone`, I got the following errors:

[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHddw.png).

Additional information:

- My Xcode-project file layout: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik3EL.png)
- My podfile: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMewE.png)

I’m relatively new to implementing 3rd party applications, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. That makes them searchable, and makes it easier for others to get the actual code/data/config from your question for testing.

Comment: StackOverflow works best if you ask a specific question. At the moment you're stating a problem you've encountered and asking for any advice. Can you ask a more targeted question... and make it a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Podfile, change `use_frameworks!` to `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`

FirebaseAnalytics is a static framework and linking it into the app's dynamic framework causes it to be linked into the app twice.